# How to change environment variable in shell executing a C program from that C program?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I want to change the value of `PATH` variable inside the C program and then see the changed value in the shell using which I run this program.

Doing something like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main () {

    char *path = getenv ("PATH");
    printf ("%s\n\n", path);
    setenv ("PATH", strcat (path, ":~/myNewPath/"), 1);
    printf ("%s\n\n", path);

    int pid = fork ();
    if (pid == -1)
        abort ();
    if (pid == 0) {

    } else {
        // use execlp? how? source? any hints?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I use `source` command in the `exec*` system call. What will be the syntax to update this `PATH` variable in the shell backwards?

Comment: Note: `setenv ("PATH", strcat (path, ":~/myNewPath/"), 1);` will probably segfault.

Comment: @wildplasser no it won't. why?

Comment: Because you cannot safely append characters to the string pointed at by the pointervalue returned by getenv(). If your stcat() doesn't segfault, it's purely by coincident/luck. Also: getenv() can return NULL.

Comment: yeah, but it wasn't the actual question. well thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: wildplasser is quite right: it probably *won't* segfault because the string is in a larger region of writable memory (as described in the ABI document I linked to) but it probably *will* overwrite adjacent data (most likely, other environment strings).

Comment: And there is an additional problem: the tilde will not be expanded, since there is no {ksh,bash} shell involved. (the linux man page is rather vague about this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is impossible.  There is no way for a subprocess to change its parent's environment variables.

To understand *why* it is impossible, look at the signature of [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve)

```
int execve(const char *program, char *const *argv, char *const *envp);
```

which is paired with the *true* signature of `main` on Unix systems

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
```

and perhaps you begin to understand that as far as the kernel is concerned, the environment variables are *a second set of command line arguments*.  That they *appear* to be independently accessible via `getenv` and `setenv` etc, and *appear* to inherit from parent to child, is an illusion maintained by the C library.

For more detail on how this works, study [the x86-64 ELF ABI specification, section 3.4.1 "Initial Stack and Register State"](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf#subsection.3.4.1) paying particular attention to figure 3.9 which shows the layout of the data copied by `execve` onto the newly created stack.  (The document linked is specific to one CPU architecture, but the way this works is generally consistent across modern Unixes; fine details will of course vary from CPU to CPU and OS to OS.)